# What security issues are there with remote access for firewalls, routers, etc.?

Tags: firewalls, router, ports

I am currently looking into cybersecurity for small businesses and it is something I have become very interested in. One of the questions in the questionnaire is:

> 6. Confirm that any remote administrative interface has been disabled on all firewall (or similar) devices

I have been looking at remote access and I can only seem to find ways how to configure it. I was curious on the security issues this poses. I presume that it requires more ports to be open for this to work? What other security implications does this cause?

Answer (score 4):

Basically every "remote access" feature is a potential attack vector, allowing a malicious actor to perform attacks on your device.

For example, if you have a outdated cisco firewall, even if you have the most complex password, an malicious attacker could perform a [buffer overflow](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/26233/) on the authentication step and maybe get access to your server.

Few recommendations would be:

- Disable any insecure protocol on your device (Telnet, FTP, etc..), keep only SSH or encrypted protocols.
- [Implement whitelists](https://serverfault.com/questions/586835/how-to-whitelist-or-deny-enable-mode-ip-address-to-cisco-3750-switch) to allow only very specific IPs to connect to the SSH. Never leave remote-access ports open to the internet or to non-trusted networks;
- If it's possible, implement a [secure jump server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_server), to ensure only authorized people will have access to the SSH interface of the device. If you have a jumpserver, the only IP that should have access to the SSH interface of the firewall should be the jump server IP.
- Keep a good access management practice, ensure password complexity and enforce password expiration for user-accounts.

Comment: I would add regular password expiry to that last point too!

Comment: Good idea, I just edited to include that